# How to get font from JTextArea to implement it to pdf document using itextpdf?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext, jtextarea

I want to create a pdf document with itextpdf with a similar font/color as in the JTextArea in java..
I have used ***Document.add(JTextArea.getText())*** but it only creates pdf without any formatting styles.

Comment: **A `JTextArea` does not support formatting. It is for plain text documents.** You might have more success using a `JEditorPane` or a `JTextPane` which **do** support text formatting.

Comment: @AndrewThompson There is a method called `setFont` for components. You mean it doesn't work for JTextArea?

Comment: And also there is a sample here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html with a line  `textArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));`

Comment: JTextArea supports font. I have used it. But i want to get these applied font from the JTextArea and set it to the pdf document created from itextpdf....